# Potential Infinite Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm currently doing a problem on freeCodeCamp and every time I hit "run tests" with the code below, the tab crashes.

I initially assumed I had an infinite loop, but if I do, I can't seem to identify it.

The issue seems to be "return arr".

If I return anything else (i.e. 5, "poo",), the tab doesn't crash.

Also, if I use "console.log(arr)" instead of "return arr". The updated (as a result of the for-loop) "arr" shows up in the console (not freeCodeCamp's console thing, my own console).

I ran this same code (with "return arr") here: [code](https://repl.it/DrCu/1)

& it works just fine when you hit "Run".

```js
    function sumFibs(num) {
        var arr = [0, 1];
    
        for (i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    
            arr[i] = arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1];
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
    
    alert(sumFibs(2));
```

Any ideas as to why this code is crashing freeCodeCamp?

Note: stackoverflow recommends "C" as one of my tags, does this mean some of my syntax is not in correct JavaScript format?...

Comment: I just ran it in FF 49 and it ran fine, no crashes.

Comment: Hmm... seems like a bug of the platform. try to return to see if it helps:
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))

Comment: Well I don't see nothing wrong with your code but what you can do to avoid problems is to declare the variable `i` inside the loop to prevent it to be gloabal like so: `for(var i = 0; i <= num; i++ ....`

Comment: One thing I see you should probably add is "var" before the 1st i in the loop. That shouldn't cause the tab to crash, but sometimes javascript doesn't like it if you leave var out.

Comment: So, what browser do you use? Just tried firefox and chrome, works like a charme in both for me.
Scrap that. The problem is not at repl.it, as described it works there... silly me...
Anyway: there is nothing structurally wrong with your code.

Comment: Run the code snippet...it works.

Comment: I use chrome. You ran it in freeCodeCamp? It only crashes my freeCodeCamp tab when I run it in their code editor

When i run it elsewhere, it's fine, so I don't think Chrome is the issue.

Comment: @Edson then it is an issue with `freeCodeCamp` not your code. I voted to close this because the issue is not reproducible...

Comment: Oh, and your code is correct javascript format (except missing the var statement). Javascript and C syntax are very similar and this snippet would be almost identical in C.